# How to determine a sub movieclip position related to the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

Hi i have some movieclips like this one: game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand and inside the rightHand i have a thread_mc like this:

```
game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc
```

Ok so here is the thing, i need to access the thread.x and thread.y position related to the stage or substage_mc i don´t really care, but if i do this:

```
trace(game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.x);
```

I only get the thread position related to the rightHand and not to the stage. Any help here?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a function on the DisplayObject class called [localToGlobal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29)

that will give you the coordinates, but you need to keep scale in mind

Comment: Great!, i don´t know why i tried that and didn´t work the first time, thanks! now i can move on ^^.

Comment: hey daniel i don´t know if its ok to ask here again, but do you know any way of getting the position of a movieClip related to another? i don´t know why but the two movieClips i´m comparing have different localToGlobal positions and they are in the same layer but are inside different movieclips

Comment: the trick is to convert localToGlabal and assign to a point, then you go globalToLocal for the movieclip where you want to find the location.  using globalToLocal and localToGlobal is a bit confusing to start with, so reading up a bit on it and playing around might help a lot. check out this link, I think that's the same issue you might be having http://www.orlandmedia.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-use-localtoglobal-in-actionscript-3-0/

Comment: @ershin69 have a look at the links in my answer, I posted because is a method a bit tricky to use

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the localToGlobal() method.

Here you can find some useful explanation:

[Understanding localToGlobal](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/06/22/understanding-as3-localtoglobal-method/)

[Use localToGlobal in AS3](http://www.orlandmedia.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-use-localtoglobal-in-actionscript-3-0/)

Answer (score 1):

Try [localToGlobal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29):

```
var posX:int = game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.x;
var posY:int = game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.y;
trace(game_mc.substage_mc.rightHand.thread_mc.localToGlobal(new Point(posX, posY));
```